# Value of $\sum\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]*x[n]$

Tags: convolution, signal-processing, z-transform

If $x[n]=(0.5)^nu[n]$ and $y[n]=x[n]*x[n]$ then what is the value of $\sum\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}y[n]$ ?

I calculated the $z-$ transform of $x[n]$ and then applied the accumulation property of $z-$transform. $$X(z) = \frac{1}{1-0.5z^{-1}}\\
Y(z) = \bigg(\frac{1}{1-0.5z^{-1}}\bigg)^2\\
\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}y[n] \longleftrightarrow \bigg(\frac{1}{1-0.5z^{-1}}\bigg)^2.\bigg(\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}\bigg)$$
Please point out the mistake I am doing.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If $X$ corresponds to $x[n]$, it does not follow that $X^2$ corresponds to $x[n]^2$.  So your formula for $Y$ is wrong.  Is $x[n]=0$ for $n<0$?  If so, your sum is $\sum_0^\infty y[n]$.

Comment: $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}y[n] = Y(z=1)$